# Reorder Entry Fields in Channel

Tags: ee3, custom-order-fields

I have a channel with several entry fields.

FieldType 1
FieldType 2
FieldType 3

I would like to reorder them in the CP so when a user creates a new entry the fieldtypes follow a different order.

FieldType 3
FieldType 1
FieldType 2

In EE2, I only had to change the "order" for each entry field.

I cannot find this option in EE3 anywhere.
That said, how can I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer (after a little digging around).  It's still possible to reorder the entry fields, but it is now found under the channel manager in 'layouts'.  :)